# asmx webservice on IIS6 gives a 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-6, asmx

I'm stuck with deploying a simple webservice to an IIS6 on a W2K3 server and hope someone can help me..

The server has Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 installed.
The webapplication has the default 3.5 web.config

As soon as I xcopy a simple webservice (just an .asmx file without codebehind) to the server I get the following error:

> ### Server Error in '/vd' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /vd/ws/EmptyService.asmx
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

When I copy other files (html, aspx, ..) to that folder they render just fine.
So I have a feeling it's an issue with the asmx mapping but don't know where and what to correct?
Hoping this is familiar to some of you..

```
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: If you can solve the problem by copying out the missing files, why is that not an OK solution?

Comment: you can try rerunning aspnet_regiis utility, sometimes that can help.

Comment: @mikey thanks for the suggestion, I ran aspnet_regiis -i again (second time today :) from the v2.0.50727 folder but doesn't help

Comment: @E.J.Brennan If I only knew what the missing files were... asmx is mapped to System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory and System.Web.Extensions? I copied over System.Web.Extensions.dll but that didn't help

Comment: Oops, never mind.. seems it's related to the webservice being placed in a subfolder of a virtual directory..

Comment: Misunderstood your question - thought you said copying out the files solved the asmx problem, now I see you said/meant that *other* files worked when they copied out...my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, *so stupid of me.*. 
Turned out I had a bad section in my web.config, I had been so dumb of specifying my own wsdlHelpGenerator for branding purposes and then forgot to copy that page over... It's exactly as the error said...  "the resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed ..."

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
  <wsdlHelpGenerator href="GLSWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx"/>
</webServices>
```